# How to set the maximum necessary size of a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a non-editable `JTextArea`.  I want the size of this `JTextArea` to be no larger than needed to contain the text it has.  However, if I expand the component containing it, the `JTextArea` will expand as well, leaving annoying empty space.  I am not putting it in a `JScrollPane` (I cannot use a `JScrollPane` in this instance).  The container that has the `JTextArea` is using `BoxLayout`.

So, basically, I have this:

```
_____________________________
|adfadfvfvanalfvnavlavnaklvf|
|afdviadanklfvnaflanvlakdnfv|
|efvavsavasv                |
|                           |
|___________________________|
```

And I want this:

```
_____________________________
|adfadfvfvanalfvnavlavnaklvf|
|afdviadanklfvnaflanvlakdnfv|
|efvavsavasv________________|
```

RELEVENT CODE:

```
private void initializeAllComponents(){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    this.setHeader();
    this.add(header);

    this.setDescription();//This is the JTextArea
    this.add(desc);

    this.setBody();
    this.add(body);

    this.setFooters();
}

private void setDescription(){
    desc = new JTextArea(skill.getDesc());
    desc.setFont(new Font("URW Chancery L", Font.ITALIC, 16));
    desc.setBackground(new Color(218, 217, 199));
    desc.setEditable(false);
    desc.setLineWrap(true);
    desc.setWrapStyleWord(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code? Also, what you'll probably want to do is place the `JTextArea` in a `JPanel`, and then add that `JPanel` to the container so the `JPanel` will be resized, instead of the `JTextArea`.

Comment: @MirorredFate, I'm assuming `this` is a `JFrame`?

Comment: No, `this` is a `JPanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the JTextArea in the north part of a `BorderLayout`, e.g.

```
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

It will then use only as much space as necessary.

Note: If you need line wrapping don't forget `textArea.setLineWrap(true);`.

Comment: Yeah, this works.  I guess I will just add everything to `JPanels` using the north borderlayout...  I have to say, I hope the JVM really really optimizes everything because I am using like octally nested components.

Answer (score -2):

I would use

```
desc.setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());
```

to minimize the size of desc, since the preferred size of a JTextArea is defined by the number of rows and columns.